# How to display <li> element's content in one line?

Tags: javascript, html, css

[image]

The picture above is an unordered list and I'm unable to make the `li`'s content in a single line. I have set a `max-width` and `overflow-x: auto;`

expecting output:

Blender  Adobe After Effects  Hitfilm Pro  Adobe Premiere Pro

Comment: You would have to increase the size of the pills to make the text display in a single line

Comment: css `white-space: nowrap` might help

Comment: Please add your code

Comment: Please add more code into your question. By changing `display` property to `block`, you can assign each `<li>` element to a separate line

Comment: @yyyy I'm got the expected output. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

(seting the display property to inline for all the lists,
Or set its cotainer - which is obvi  or  to flex)
are reasons why they all show up in one line.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways to prevent the text wrapping. One way is a min-width of the value of the largest string, "Adobe After Effects". The character count is 19. With that you can set "min-width: 20ch;" 1 ch is equal to the width of the character 0. It's a relative property which will make it responsive regardless of the font-size. You may have to adjust the number slightly as not all characters are of equal width.

Answer (score 0):

Set the `UL` element to `display:flex` like this

```css
Ul {
display:flex;
justify-content: space-around;
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li>one</li>
    <li>two</li>
    <li>three</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `display:inline` style to `LI` element.

```css
li
{
     display:inline;
     padding: 15px;
}
```

```html
    <ul>
       <li>one</li>
       <li>two</li>
       <li>three</li>
    </ul>
```